# Gravity's potential energy is it measurable?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

In vacuum all object fall with no resistance and the object keeps on accelerating without stopping at a particular velocity. If i manage to make the fall to take place for 20 sec, then will the object get accelerated every second at a rate of 9.81 $~\rm m/s^2$? what is the max potential energy of the gravity? will the object stop accelerating in vacuum after a particular point? in infinite height of fall will it accelerate infinitely?

Comment: "in infinite height of fall will it accelerate infinitely?" Yes. But the acceleration won't be constant.

Comment: how it is getting disturbed the acceleration due to g?

Comment: Gravitational acceleration is (approximately) constant only if you are close to the surface of the planet. The actual formula is $a = G M r^{-2}$, where $r$ is the distance from the center of the planet and $M$ the mass of the planet.

Comment: If you fall to earth from an infinite distance, your speed at impact will be 11.2 km/s - the same as the speed required to escape earth to infinity. I'm ignoring the sun (and planets) here.